# grep output not same as "re.findall()" output in python3

Tags: python, regex, unix, grep

Here is my input file

**input.txt**

```
www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_003157.1 rs 1123   
www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_006157 dd 12   
www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_021018.2 ff 121
www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_000908.2 rs10472828-?
```

**Expected output**

```
NM_003157.1
NM_006157
NP_021018.2
NM_000908.2
```

**my regex**

```
egrep "N[A-Z]_[0-9]{1,}(\.[1-9])*" input.txt
```

**my code**

```
f=open("input.txt")
for i in f:
    print(re.findall("N[A-Z]_[0-9]{1,}(\.[1-9])*",i.strip()))`
```

python output:

```
[]
[]
['.3']
[]
```

The output of my grep matches perfectly to my expected output. But when I use that same regex into my python3 code, I am getting improper output.

Comment: 1. your regexes are not the same, 2. what's the wrong output?

Comment: you should be using `parse_qs` (and `urlsplit` friends) to parse query strings, not regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have one `.` too many in your Python pattern that the `egrep` version lacks; remove it.

Next, `re.findall()` returns *capturing groups*, not the whole match, if there are such groups. Make the group non-capturing by using `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`:

```
re.findall(r'N[A-Z]_[0-9]+(?:\.[1-9])*', i.strip())
```

Now `re.findall()` produces a list with one match per line:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''\
... www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_003157.1 rs 1123   
... www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_006157 dd 12   
... www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_021018.2 ff 121
... www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/viewer.fcgi?db=nucleotide&amp;val=NM_000908.2 rs10472828-?
... '''
>>> f = text.splitlines()
>>> for i in f:
...     print(re.findall(r"N[A-Z]_[0-9]+(?:\.[1-9])*", i.strip()))
... 
['NM_003157.1']
['NM_006157']
['NM_021018.2']
['NM_000908.2']
```

For just one match per line you'd be better of using `re.search()`, then call `MatchObject.group()` on the result:

```
>>> for i in f:
...     print(re.search(r"N[A-Z]_[0-9]+(?:\.[1-9])*", i.strip()).group())
... 
NM_003157.1
NM_006157
NM_021018.2
NM_000908.2
```

Comment: The backslash will be "auto-escaped" if the following character doesn't work as an escape character, so `"\."` becomes `"\\."` implicitly, so that's not the problem. The extra `.` is, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Indeed, I realised this later on. It is the capturing group that is the biggest problem here.

Comment: @diablo8226: "It not working" is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: @diablo8226: it very much is working; I included some demo output.

Comment: i got my mistake.thnx

Answer (score 1):

Through grep with `oP` parameters,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=;val=)\S*(?=\s)' file
NM_003157.1
NM_006157
NM_021018.2
NM_000908.2
```

A lookbehind is used to lookafter the string `;val=` and match all the non-space characters followed by a space character.

Through egrep,

```
$ egrep -o "N[A-Z]_[0-9]{1,}(\.[1-9])*" file
NM_003157.1
NM_006157
NM_021018.2
NM_000908.2
```

In the `egrep` you misses the `-o` parameter which tells the `egrep` to print only the matched strings.

Comment: i wanted to know wat is wrong in findall. the grep was jsut to show the output

Comment: i donno why a long python code a simple grep will does the job.

Comment: python code is just a small module of a another code.

Comment: @diablo8226 updated my answer for egrep.